# Extracting day, week and month from another database using sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a database (not mine) that I need to extract the date from and put it in another database (mine) and have separate columns for the day, week and month. In the original database it appears like 05-APR-10 but I just can't get it appear in separate columns.

This is what I've done so far:

```
CREATE TABLE Seasontime (
Seasontime number(2) PRIMARY KEY,
Month number(2) NOT NULL,
Week number(2) NOT NULL,
Day number(2) NOT NULL);

CREATE SEQUENCE Seasontime_Seq
START WITH  0
INCREMENT BY 1
MINVALUE 0
NOCACHE
NOCYCLE;

insert into Seasontime
    select Seasontime_seq.nextval,
           Month,
           Week,
           Day
    from   (
            select extract(Month from PDate) as Month,
                   extract(Week from PDate) as Week,
                   extract(Day from PDate) as Day
            From notmydatabase.performance
           );
```

The last bit doesn't work so if anyone can help me that would be great
Thanks in advance

Comment: As both are different databases, use `databasename.tablename` to access the tables. What error do you get?

Comment: Are you sure this is valid T-SQL (MS SQL Server) code? Looks like Oracle to me

Comment: Prerak: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis is the error I get at the moment (I've had all different ones all day)

Comment: Zoff: thanks, I didn't relised I'd tagged it wrong

Comment: What's the datatype of the PDate field in the other database? what error do you get?

Comment: StevieG: It is a date type

Comment: FYI - in Oracle lingo this would be a separate schema, not a separate database.

Comment: David: Ah ok thanks. I'm not very good with the lingo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WEEK` isn't a valid field for [the `extract()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions059.htm#SQLRF00639). You'd need to use `to_char()` to get the week number:

```
select Seasontime_seq.nextval,
       Month,
       Week,
       Day
from   (
        select extract(Month from PDate) as Month,
               to_number(to_char(PDate, 'WW')) as Week,
               extract(Day from PDate) as Day
        From notmydatabase.performance
       );
```

You may prefer to use `to_char()` rather than `extract()` for the other fields too for consistency. You might also need the ISO week number, which you can get with [the `'IW'` date format element](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#r21c1-t65) instead of `'WW'`.

Or possibly, if you want the week of the month rather than the week of the year, just `'W'`; but that would perhaps suggest you want the day of the week too, not the day of the month that `extract()` gives you.

Comment: This works as you have posted it. When I add 'insert into Seasontime' it doesn't. Error: ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column Any ideas?

Comment: @LisaDuffin - you've created your table with `Seasontime number(2)`; if the query gets more than 100 results the sequence will go into 3 digits, giving that error on insert. Make it a larger number, or unrestricted as `number(38)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `extract` to get the week from the date column. Try using to_char instead:

```
insert into Seasontime
select Seasontime_seq.nextval,
       Month,
       Week,
       Day
from   (
        select to_char(PDate, 'mm') as Month,
               to_char(PDate, 'WW) as Week,
               to_char(PDate, 'dd') as Day
        From notmydatabase.performance
       );
```

Comment: This comes up with a new error: ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorted it now. Thank you very much for your help